# Label for input type email in a form

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, user-research, human-interface-guideline

Is there any UX consideration for the label for an email,some labels that i could think of are:

- Email ID
- Email Address
- Email

Comment: Email is enough. Just add the html5 attribute "email" to the input field, and you are ok.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I definitely recommend that you use the word "**Email**" together with a simple general placeholder like "email@example.com".

**Email ID:**
The ID part sounds confusing. It will probably confuse the user too.

**Email Address:**
For a form element title, this un-necessarily long. Shorter text is ideal for forms.

[image: User Email Form Title]

For more insight see previous answers here:
[Which label text is good for "Enter email address"?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50579/which-label-text-is-good-for-enter-email-address)

and here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/best-practices-on-common-person-fields-name-email-address-gender-etc

EDIT: Thanks to @njzk2 and @thunderblaster for valid points. I've corrected the sample form to reflect your insights.

Comment: I would remove the `:` from the label, I don't think it is necessary

Comment: [`domain.com`](http://www.domain.com) is a valid, privately owned domain.  `example.com` is specifically prohibited from being registered to be used in examples such as this.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for the correction. You're 100% spot on.

Comment: @thunderblaster , you're right. I must admit it was quite a pleasant surprise to read that the domain: example.com is totally alright being used in forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "Email" is describing enough.
"Email ID" then again is really misleading. What ID? I understand that the email is used for identification but user might not understand that.

Answer (score -1):

Email is fine for most audiences (especially combined with the hint text), but if your users are less tech-savvy they may find it Email Address clearer and less ambiguous.